# Can event Handler propagate between events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

please need your help to more understand this point, what I'm trying to do is to edit the task after posting it adding flag if the task needs to be edited or not with 'edit' flag

always give me the following error You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`

could me to solve that error , please

so App.js:

```
const App=()=> {

const [tasks,settasks]=useState([])
// const [title,setTitle] = useState('')

const AddHandler=(new_task)=>{
    const new_arr = [...tasks,new_task]
    settasks(new_arr)
}
const onKeyDownHandler=(event,taskIndex)=>{
    if(taskIndex){
        console.log('test')
    }else{
        const new_task = {'title':event.target.value,'edit':false}
        if(event.keyCode === 13){
            AddHandler(new_task)
        }
    }


}

const deleteHandler=(taskIndex)=>{
    const new_tasks = [...tasks]
    new_tasks.splice(taskIndex,1)
    settasks(new_tasks)
}




const EditHandler=(editIndex) => {
        const new_tasks = [...tasks]
        new_tasks[editIndex].edit= true
        settasks(new_tasks)

   }



return (
<div className={classes.App}>

    <h3>To do List ...</h3>
        <div className={classes.Form}>
            <Input  inputtype="text" typing={onKeyDownHandler} />
            <Button>Add</Button>
        </div>
        <Tasks
               tasks={tasks}
               edit={EditHandler}
               typing={onKeyDownHandler}
               delete={deleteHandler}/>
</div>


);
}

export default App;
```

in tasks.js:

```
const Tasks=(props)=>{


return(
    <div>
        {props.tasks.map((task,index)=>(
            <Task triggeredit={task.edit}
                  key={index}
                  index={index}
                  click={()=>props.delete(index)}
                  edit={()=>props.edit(index)}
                  title={task.title}
                  typing={props.typing}
                  address={index}


            />
        ))}
        {/*<input onKeyDown={(event)=>props.typing(event,1)}/>*/}


    </div>
)
}
export default Tasks
```

in task.js:

```
const Task=(props)=>{

return (
    <div className={classes.Task}>
        <Input inputtype="checkbox" inputstyle='CheckBox'/>
        {props.triggeredit ?
            <Input

            index ={props.index}
            inputtype="text"
            value={props.title}
            typing={props.typing}/>:<p>{props.title}</p>}
        <Button  click={props.edit}><i className="fa fa-edit"></i></Button>
        <Button click={props.click} style="Danger"><i className="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></Button>
    </div>
)
}


export default Task
```

in Input.js:

```
const Input =(props) => {

let InputHtml = null
switch (props.inputtype) {
    case('text'):
        InputHtml = <input placeholder="Add Your Tasks"
                           type="text"
                           value={props.value}
                           onKeyDown={(event)=>props.typing(event,props.index)}
                           className={classes.InputElement}
                           ref={props.refs}

        />
        break
    case ('checkbox'):
        InputHtml =  <input type="checkbox" className={classes.InputElement}/>
        break
    default:
        InputHtml = <input placeholder="Add Your Tasks" type="text" className={classes.InputElement}/>
        break
}

return (
    <div className={[classes.Input,classes[props.inputstyle]].join(' ')}>
        {InputHtml}
    </div>
)
}
export default Input
```

Comment: In input.js it seems like you are managing only keyboard events. This should resolve your issue: case('text'):
        InputHtml = `<input placeholder="Add Your Tasks"
                           type="text"
                           value={props.value} onChange={() => yourEventHandler()}
                           onKeyDown={(event)=>props.typing(event,props.index)}
                           className={classes.InputElement}
                           ref={props.refs}

        />`

Comment: sorry i didn't get your point

Comment: guys i need your help please !

Comment: Have you tried doing what the warning suggests? Use the `onChange` handler versus the `onKeyDown`?